# Displaying the result of a logical operation in an Alert box

Tags: javascript, html

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

The following is my Javascript code in the .js file:

```
function call_alert()
{
    alert (result);
}

var a = true; , b = false;

var test1 = (a && a);

var test2 = (a && b);

var test3 = (b && b);

var result = "Are they true? \n";

result += "1:" +test1+;
```

I haven't included the variables test2 and test3 for the sake of simplicity.

My HTML is just the standard `<body onload ="call_alert()">`.

Comment: `var a = true; , b = false;`: remove that semicolon in the middle.

Comment: Look in the browser's error console. Fix the errors you see there.

Comment: i think you close function after alertfunction call_alert()

{

    alert (result);
}

Comment: Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o9gmgzus/

Comment: `+test1+;` is a syntax error. Is that code inside another function? If not, then `result` is not in the scope of `call_alert` (at least this can be sometimes an issue). Simply put the rest of your code inside the function body, at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this will work fine

```
function call_alert()
{
    alert (result);
}

var a = true; 
var b = false;

var test1 = (a && a);

var test2 = (a && b);

var test3 = (b && b);

var result = "Are they true? \n";

result += "1:" +test1;
```

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure of the what you are trying to do but i'll give it a go.

```
var a = true, b = false;

function callAlert() {
   alert (result);
}

var test1 = (a && a);
var test2 = (a && b);
var test3 = (b && b);

var result = "Are they true? y" + "/" + "n";

result += " 1 " + test1;
```